# How to enumerate starting with custom number

Tags: python

Using:

```
myList=['One','Two','Three'[
for i,each in enumerate(myList):
    print i,each
```

results to:

```
0,'One'
1,'Two'
2,'Three'
```

As we can see enumerate starts iterating with i=0, then 1, then 2 and so one.
What if I would like to start with other than zero value, lets say it want it to be 5. So the result would be:

```
5,'One'
6,'Two'
7,'Three'
```

Is it doable?

Comment: In the future, you'll find the answer much faster if you just [look it up](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass in the starting number:

```
for i,each in enumerate(myList,5): #  <- start at 5

myList=['One','Two','Three']
for i,each in enumerate(myList,5):
    print i,each
5 One
6 Two
7 Three
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass `start=5` to [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i,each in enumerate(myList, start=5):
```